# Fatal Error while cloning from Heroku git repo

Tags: git, heroku

I have been getting this error since yesterday -

```
remote: Counting objects: 789, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (366/366), done.
remote: Total 789 (delta 306), reused 783 (delta 300)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I am not able to clone one of my repositories from Heroku. I am able to clone all the others and able to push changes successfully to this one. I saw the same sort of questions on stackoverflow but they were mostly not answered or had a slight variation in the error message.

System: Mac

Comment: can someone comment why it needs to be closed?

Comment: has anyone ever cloned that repo? are you the only one who cant clone it?

Comment: Yes I have a copy on my system. I have done it in the past many times. But now I am not able to do it.

Comment: Try pushing your local copy to the remote, then try cloning again. Your remote might be corrupt.

Comment: Same error. Push pull are working fine. Only clone is failing.

Comment: Yes I am able to pull.